Power calculations for Cohen's Kappa
I'd like to determine the required sample size to measure inter-rater reliability of a binary diagnostic test. There are two raters. The expected rate of positive diagnoses is 7.5% for both raters.

How do I determine the required sample size so that the analysis is adequately powered? I used the irr package in R, but the resulting numbers seem too low:
irr::N.cohen.kappa(
  rate1 = 0.075,
  rate2 = 0.075,
  k1 = 0.6,
  k0 = 0,
  alpha = 0.05,
  power = 0.8,
  twosided = FALSE
)
# [1] 25

With N=25 and prevalence of 7.5%, there would be only ~2 positive cases. Is my interpretation correct?

Is it right to assume k0 (the value of Kappa under the null hypothesis) to be 0, i.e., no agreement other than that by chance? I've read somewhere that this should be the lowest acceptable Kappa, e.g., 0.4, not 0.


Thank you.
